# Interface for file in custom Integromat app

Tags: make.com, integromat-apps

If a module should output a file with binary data, what should its interface look like so that the file can be mapped correctly in other modules in a scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interface should contain data and filename.

```json
[
  {
        "name": "data",
        "type": "buffer",
        "label": "Data",
        "semantic": "file:data"
    },
    {
        "name": "fileName",
        "label": "File Name",
        "type": "text",
        "semantic": "file:name"
    },
]
```

You can take a look at the Dropbox example: https://www.integromat.com/app/dropbox/5/module/getFile#tab:interface